# Best practice on flowing functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I receive data from request, and before display it I want to process it, like add/format/generate/order the raw content just received.

Here the way I receive data, and how I send it to the `processData` function

```
this.httpService.get(`this/is/my/url`, body).then((data) => {
    this.processData(data).then((result) => {
        this.data = result;
    }, (error) => {
        this.error = error;
    });
}, (error) => {
    this.error = error;
});
```

Note the `processData` function may need to call promises functions.
I see two ways to write the `processData` function :

**First way**

```
function processData(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        step1();

        function step1() {
            this.myService.yolo(data).then({
                //...
                step2();
            }, (error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        }

        function step2() {
            this.myService.foo(data).then({
                //...
                step3();
            }, (error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        }

        function step3() {
            this.myService.bar(data).then({
                //...
                step4();
            }, (error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        }

        function step4() {
            //...
            resolve(data);
        }
   });
}
```

**Second way**

```
function processData(data) {
    step1().then((result) => {
        step2().then((result) => {
            step3().then((result) => {
                step4();
                return data;
            }, (error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        }, (error) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
    });

    function step1() {
        //...
    }

    function step2() {
        //...
    }

    function step3() {
        //...
    }

    function step4() {
        //...
    }
}
```

The second way makes me feel more logical, because you don't need to see the `step` functions content to understand what's going on, but I find the notation so confusing !
With 10 steps, this is unreadable.

So I was wondering what would be the good way to do that !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing missing from how you're using promises is you're not *returning* anything from your `then` callbacks, which is how you chain promises together in a useful way.

Your `processData` can look like this:

```
function processData(data) {
    step1().then(step2).then(step3).then(step4);

    function step1() {
        //...
    }

    // ...
}
```

...where the steps look like this:

```
function step1() {
    return this.myService.yolo(data).then(result => {
        return transformedResult;
    });
}
```

...which means, of course, that unless they're complex, you don't need to break them into their own functions:

```
function processData(data) {
    return this.myService.yolo(data)
        .then(result => {
            return /*...`result` transformed in some way...*/;
        })
        .then(result => anotherAsyncCall(result))
        .then(result => {
            return /*...`result` transformed again... */;
        })
        .then(result => anotherAsyncCall(result)) // If no transformation needed when passing it on
        .then(/*etc.*/);
}
```

This is because every call to `then` returns a promise. The promise is either resolved with the value you return from your `then` callback, or if you return a promise it's resolved/rejected based on the resolution/rejection of that promise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! And how does it work to handle promise errors ? Like if step2 fails, go step4 ?

Comment: @Citizen: Rejections are propagated until they reach the first handler registered for a rejection, skipping any that are registered only for resolutions. So `a.then(b).then(c).catch(...)` will (effectively) go straight from `a` to the `catch` if `a` rejects instead of resolving.